# How to Hide Interactive Report Setting Area in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

[image]I want to hide Interactive Report Setting/Filters Area.

I found to hide Interactive Grid's Report setting area in Interactive Grid Cookbook

```
function(config) {
config.reportSettingsArea = false;
// may want to disable the highlights feature. Comment out this code to make initial highlight settings
apex.util.getNestedObject(config, "views.grid.features").highlight = false;
return config;}
```

Comment: Go into attributes and find the setting to show/hide toolbar

Comment: want to hide Filter conditions area only which took up too much space as showing in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove completely the settings regions of an interactive report you can do as follows:

1. Give your Interactive Report region an static id (under your regions attributes scroll over "*Advanced*" and then "*static id*");
2. Under your page properties (first tab on the left on page designer mode) :

[image]

Go to CSS section and then paste the following code in the attribute "In line" (I'm assuming your *static id* is **"IR_ORDERS"**:

```
#IR_ORDERS_control_panel{
     display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(if you are using ver 18.1 up)

GO to **Attributes** then under **Search Bar** find **Finder Drop down** and set to **No**.

Comment: this doesn't work nor does it address the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

To remove completely the settings regions of an interactive Grid you can do
past the below code in PAGE>>CSS>>inline `.a-IG-controlsContainer { display:none; }`